# overlay lexis_grid with heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a lexis_grid for a series of events for a synthetic cohorot of people aged 0:80 over the time period 1900-2021. What I'd like to get is something that looks a little like this:

[image]

Which I have [taken from this article](https://file:///C:/Users/Nora%20Schwaller/Downloads/Visualizing_compositional_data_on_the_Lexis_surfac.pdf).

I have some dummy code created below:

```
library('dplyr')
library('LexisPlotR')
library('lubridate')
library('ggplot2')

df <- data.frame(
  year <-  sample(c(1900:2021), 1000, TRUE),
  age <-    sample(c(0:80), 1000, TRUE),
  event <- sample(c(0:5), 1000, TRUE)
)

colnames(df) <- c("year", "age", "event")


mylexis <- lexis_grid(year_start = 1900, 
           year_end = 2021, 
           age_start = 0,
           age_end = 80,
           delta = 10
           )
```

And I can create a heatmap in ggplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = age, fill = event)) + geom_tile()
```

But I have been unsuccessful at combining them. These were my best guesses:

```
mylexis + geom_tile(df, mapping = aes(x = year(year), y = age, fill = event))
mylexis + ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = age, fill = event)) + geom_tile()
```

Any advice on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert your `year` variable to a proper date:

```
library(ggplot2)

mylexis + 
  geom_tile(data = df, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")), y = age, fill = event))
```

[image]

**EDIT** A bit hacky but also a quick approach to change the order of the3 layers would be to manipulate the `layers` of the `ggplot2` object like so, i.e. move the `geom_tile` (layer 3) to the first position (But I have to admit that at least for your example data the difference is hardly visible):

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- mylexis + 
  geom_tile(data = df, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")), y = age, fill = event))

p$layers <- p$layers[c(3, 1, 2)]

p
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks so much. Any way to get the lexis grid lines on top? The actual dataset has a lot more points and it's basically covering it.

Comment: See my edit. A bit hacky but works.