# recreating a lexis grid using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following up to an answer I [got to this question on creating a lexis grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75378008/overlay-lexis-grid-with-heatmap/75378157?noredirect=1#comment133006157_75378157). While the answer got me to the point where I could overlay my data with a lexis grid, due to the density of my data, the lexis grid was completely obscured by the fill. I got a hacky sort of response for bringing the grid to the front with the solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- mylexis + 
  geom_tile(data = df, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")), y = age, fill = event))

p$layers <- p$layers[c(3, 1, 2)]

p
```

This worked initially, however, as I added more detail to the plot that created more layers, it sort of fell apart as a solution.

So I am now trying to completely circumvent the lexis_grid command and the LexisPlotR package. Instead, I just want to add a sequence of vertical, horizontal, and diagonal lines.

What I want is along the lines of the following image, [from this article](https://www.demographic-research.org/volumes/vol36/21/):

[image]

This is what I am trying:

```
library('dplyr')
library('ggplot2')
library('viridis')

df <- data.frame(
  year <-  sample(c(1900:2021), 1000, TRUE),
  age <-    sample(c(0:80), 1000, TRUE),
  event <- sample(c(0:5), 1000, TRUE)
)

colnames(df) <- c("year", "age", "event")


ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=age, fill=event)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0, 80, by=10)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1900,2030, by=10)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=seq(0, 80, by=10), slope=1) + 
  labs(fill = "Count",
       title = "Events")
```

Which gets me the following:

[image]

The problem is, I don't know why there are dots below the 0 line and to the left of the 1900 line. And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong with the geom_abline, but I can't get the diagonals to work for anything.

Comment: Side notes: never use `<-` _inside_ a call to `data.frame`, use `=` instead; this is why you need to `colnames(df) <-` afterwards. If you look in your environment after calling `data.frame`, you'll notice that you have objects named `year`, `age`, and `event`, because the `<-` operator created the objects; since it created objects, it did not create them as named arguments to `data.frame`, so it didn't see the names themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the tiles fill to the left of 1900 and below 0 is that the tiles are *centered* on the `x`/`y` coordinates, and they spill out in all directions based in `width`/`height`. I don't know of any way of showing dots with finite size that don't visually appear to spill out outside of the domain of values.

The reason your `abline`s do not show is that your intercept is assuming a `0,0` origin on the plot, but your x axis starts at 1900. The "real" (y-)intercept is far below 0; 1900 below, to be precise. If we accommodate that (and widen the range a bit), we can see the diagonal lines.

Reproducible data (using `set.seed`) and correcting for the unadvised use of `<-` inside of `data.frame`:

```r
library('dplyr')
library('ggplot2')
library('viridis')
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  year  = sample(c(1900:2021), 1000, TRUE),
  age   = sample(c(0:80), 1000, TRUE),
  event = sample(c(0:5), 1000, TRUE)
)
head(df)
#   year age event
# 1 1948  66     1
# 2 2000  13     4
# 3 1964  72     0
# 4 1924  55     1
# 5 1973  43     2
# 6 1999  54     1
```

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=age, fill=event)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0, 80, by = 10)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1900, 2030, by = 10)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=seq(0, 200, by = 10) - 2020, slope = 1) + 
  labs(fill = "Count", title = "Events")
```

[image: ggplot manual lexis grid]

The use of `seq(0, 200, by = 10)` is because we have `80/10=8` lines to draw originating from the left-border, and `(2020-1900)/10=12` lines to draw originating from the bottom-border. You can change to `seq(-10, 200, by = 10) - 2020` to fill in that last diagonal. It's okay to over-draw some ablines, they will be optimized out of the plot. (For instance, `seq(-50, 300, by = 10) - 2020` works without otherwise affecting the x/y limits.)